# Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS doesn't start/boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

I am new for Linux environment. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and used for a while. I just turned my PC on and it showed me GRUB prompt. I do not know how that happened. Please, any help? I have my data in the laptop that I am afraid to lose so I did not try to fix it myself.

Here are the images of my PC.

[image: booting 1]

[image: booting 2]

Additional - and in fact, key, info:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't attach pics, it says i have to have 10 reputations

Comment: add the url into the q and someone will edit it into an image.

Comment: Select kernel 4.4.0-38 kernel and hit 'enter' - on second screen You attached. Is then the system starts up ? - How do You partition your hard drive ?
- Do You have LVM ?
- Do You have dm-crypt (encrypted hard drive) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not able to boot normally becuase you've got a "dirty" file system on /dev/sda2.

At the GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, the choose Recovery Mode, then choose root level access. Once there, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`. Run this more than once if there are errors.

When completed, type `reboot`.

Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thank you sooooo much heynnema, your solution worked, and I got it fixed.

Comment: How did you figure it out? There is _nothing_ on this page related to `/dev/sda2`. Isn’t something missing in the current version of the question?

Comment: 'cause I'm smart... giggle. Actually, I looked at the OP's pictures that he posted at <https://s22.postimg.org/x5kqesrbl/IMG_7395.jpg>. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and could not even get into any of the recovery modes. So I used my 12.04 LTS live disk and opened a terminal. Used these commands I found:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

This ran the boot repair tool and fixed my 16.04 LTS installation. Whew! I was having a heart attack...

Hope this is helpful to someone out there. The boot repair tool helps. I think my problem was my GRUB was not functioning. The repair tool reinstalled it and the sda2 files.

<sub>This is where I found the commands for the boot repair tool: http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-boot-repair-ubuntu-1315203</sub>